# Identity Server Random "invalid_grant"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, identityserver4

Hello I have an issue with IdentityServer 4.
When we intiate a cal to IDP with Swagger for the first time I can get a token

```
[12:36:21 DBG] Getting claims for identity token for subject: 3680d5aa-4b35-4e39-a1ce-cfbc6961f4c3 and client: Idp.UserIdentitySwagger
[12:36:21 DBG] In addition to an id_token, an access_token was requested. No claims other than sub are included in the id_token. To obtain more user claims, either use the user info endpoint or set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken on the client configuration.
[12:36:21 VRB] Creating JWT identity token
[12:36:21 INF] {"ClientId": "Idp.UserIdentitySwagger", "ClientName": "Idp.UserIdentity Swagger", "RedirectUri": null, "Endpoint": "Token", "SubjectId": "3680d5aa-4b35-4e39-a1ce-cfbc6961f4c3", "Scopes": "openid profile email", "GrantType": "authorization_code", "Tokens": [{"TokenType": "id_token", "TokenValue": "****dlrQ", "$type": "Token"}, {"TokenType": "access_token", "TokenValue": "****g_rw", "$type": "Token"}], "Category": "Token", "Name": "Token Issued Success", "EventType": "Success", "Id": 2000, "Message": null, "ActivityId": "0HMJ7TTLK79RA:0000000E", "TimeStamp": "2022-07-17T12:36:21.0000000Z", "ProcessId": 1, "LocalIpAddress": "10.244.1.16:443", "RemoteIpAddress": "10.244.0.9", "$type": "TokenIssuedSuccessEvent"}
[12:36:21 VRB] Identity token issued for Idp.UserIdentitySwagger (Idp.UserIdentity Swagger) / 3680d5aa-4b35-4e39-a1ce-cfbc6961f4c3: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIzNTJFMjcwQkFDQjUwMDAwNjM1NkY3RjIwRDM0MEIwQjk3NDRCRThSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsIng1dCI6IkkxTGljTHJMVUFBR05XOV9JTk5Bc0xsMFMtZyJ9.eyJuYmYiOjE2NTgwNjEzODEsImV4cCI6MTY1ODA2NDk4MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9pZHAub3Vpb3VpZGlzY291bnQuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiSWRwLlVzZXJJZGVudGl0eVN3YWdnZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTgwNjEzODEsImF0X2hhc2giOiJFWWRZYWtpb0ZFUTN6Z19qeHZ1Umd3Iiwic19oYXNoIjoiMUxYeTNQMXpaOTZiU2lDWjBrRmNBZyIsInNpZCI6IjYzREQ4OEQ5QTQ0NEEyRDQzRDU1QUNBMjYyQTM1MTc3Iiwic3ViIjoiMzY4MGQ1YWEtNGIzNS00ZTM5LWExY2UtY2ZiYzY5NjFmNGMzIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjU4MDYxMzczLCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXX0.kyOSEob49JTd10Wmz3YMgg48MB-RRWmSJ6JB2dZeu-0r8WPOK69XXlq74bGAoyV6DwytsyTOmwb7h5Wnu5zcgbHFJ_ycGAi5PwOiO1clyDIpYW5ql__SZ2JH31ppuRg616eDaX0M2p9PFfW4MBSM1d4p69aWrbqAmuj8g833VjtZOFkZcgS6OZotqbM_zxOGLhfkzwJQtDjHdh1_imJp80fa4uv_0KOpWc62hclOXcBS8oKvgQYyeeS8AIXGrIBoNII8ZQ8yK-BrqOAjm4f1PVyyhQa8P19gXWoASQL6EHb-zCUo5VUXAu7bukBb4JNNzk8jUTCWvSUo9z4_rDdlrQ
[12:36:21 VRB] Access token issued for Idp.UserIdentitySwagger (Idp.UserIdentity Swagger) / 3680d5aa-4b35-4e39-a1ce-cfbc6961f4c3: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIzNTJFMjcwQkFDQjUwMDAwNjM1NkY3RjIwRDM0MEIwQjk3NDRCRThSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6ImF0K2p3dCIsIng1dCI6IkkxTGljTHJMVUFBR05XOV9JTk5Bc0xsMFMtZyJ9.eyJuYmYiOjE2NTgwNjEzODEsImV4cCI6MTY1ODA2NDk4MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9pZHAub3Vpb3VpZGlzY291bnQuY29tIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiSWRwLlVzZXJJZGVudGl0eVN3YWdnZXIiLCJzdWIiOiIzNjgwZDVhYS00YjM1LTRlMzktYTFjZS1jZmJjNjk2MWY0YzMiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2NTgwNjEzNzMsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwic2lkIjoiNjNERDg4RDlBNDQ0QTJENDNENTVBQ0EyNjJBMzUxNzciLCJpYXQiOjE2NTgwNjEzODEsInNjb3BlIjpbIm9wZW5pZCIsInByb2ZpbGUiLCJlbWFpbCJdLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl19.BXtDlQKqw8rGmgnLjJuWJicF2BIHPzpp48NC-aP9cpzy7dqYY2a8kI1x07vTnhX2rcEjdfqhfMIfyJuqZJBhXVtfI7R60QyfuAj3Ozpa4KGE2Y28d9Xntizf4ctwUXFLZVboH8MrXflcIiDL8s5h_c6P6W2NafYK_1m7xpU68Qq0NsxqXsaG2SZT_nph-bl_hEvfR_AfXbkDI12Z606hSqAhjP5v_TQfc6_0zveCVTiFRUMCzTzndtRSVtNrP3WPGXalOTtOaeOIUFssDvqNYeF6nch245vjw5NQQu3zUgETOSJfeO_d0c7VCeEvp_s_yCEFCVOIl2_xvWd3Hig_rw
```

I disconnect and try to login again and a “invalid_grant” is raised. I clear the cache and try again and it does not work. After several retries I can login. I think it is random error. I cannot figure out the reason behind this error. Here is the error message and the IDP configuration and the client configuration. I hope that it can help.

```
[12:42:06 DBG] A data reader was disposed.
[12:42:06 DBG] Closing connection to database 'IdpDb' on server 'tcp://XXXXXXXXXXX:5432'.
[12:42:06 DBG] Closed connection to database 'IdpDb' on server ''.
[12:42:06 DBG] tJc155MKnmvPDXowrLH4laE8GBDyxFtEveiaB/ONE4w= found in database: False
[12:42:06 DBG] authorization_code grant with value: E3661868CE07773D4612B6A32A5D10B9B0A48D00E616718C795D9ED5F6827348 not found in store.
[12:42:06 ERR] Invalid authorization code{"code": "E3661868CE07773D4612B6A32A5D10B9B0A48D00E616718C795D9ED5F6827348"}, details: {"ClientId": "Idp.UserIdentitySwagger", "ClientName": "Idp.UserIdentity Swagger", "GrantType": "authorization_code", "Scopes": null, "AuthorizationCode": "****7348", "RefreshToken": "********", "UserName": null, "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "Tenant": null, "IdP": null, "Raw": {"grant_type": "authorization_code", "code": "E3661868CE07773D4612B6A32A5D10B9B0A48D00E616718C795D9ED5F6827348", "client_id": "Idp.UserIdentitySwagger", "client_secret": "***REDACTED***", "redirect_uri": "https://identity.*******.com/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html", "code_verifier": "eMCIRwHDzhTf1YrRr651Uaqi_COopBhc7ZfOGyjRiAc"}, "$type": "TokenRequestValidationLog"}
[12:42:06 INF] {"ClientId": "Idp.UserIdentitySwagger", "ClientName": "Idp.UserIdentity Swagger", "RedirectUri": null, "Endpoint": "Token", "SubjectId": null, "Scopes": null, "GrantType": "authorization_code", "Error": "invalid_grant", "ErrorDescription": null, "Category": "Token", "Name": "Token Issued Failure", "EventType": "Failure", "Id": 2001, "Message": null, "ActivityId": "0HMJ7TTLK79RH:00000008", "TimeStamp": "2022-07-17T12:42:06.0000000Z", "ProcessId": 1, "LocalIpAddress": "10.244.1.16:443", "RemoteIpAddress": "10.244.0.9", "$type": "TokenIssuedFailureEvent"}
[12:42:06 VRB] Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.TokenErrorResult
```

IdpConfiguration

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = (t) =>
            {
                t.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("IdpDb"),
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                t.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            };
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = (t) =>
            {
                t.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("IdpDb"),
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                t.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            };
        })
        .AddProfileService<BrandeeUserProfileService>()
        .AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificate(configuration));
```

DataProtection Code:

```
  services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("TAASe")
        .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(
            new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
            {
                EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
                ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256,
            }
        )
        .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(new X509Certificate2(configuration["Certificate:Path"],
            configuration["Certificate:Password"]))
        .PersistKeysToDbContext<AppDataProtectionDbContext>()
        .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
```

Client Definition:

```
{
  "clientId": "Idp.UserIdentity Swagger",
  "clientName": "Idp.UserIdentity Swagger",
  "requireConsent": true,
  "accessTokenLifetime": 3600,
  "identityTokenLifetime": 3600,
  "allowOfflineAccess": true,
  "alwaysSendClientClaims": true,
  "secrets": [
    "secret"
  ],
  "scopes": [
    "openid","profile","email"
  ],
  "allowedGrantType": [
    "authorization_code"
  ],
  "redirectUris": [
    "https://identity.XXXXXXXXXX.com/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html"
  ],
  "corsOrigins": [
    "https://identity.XXXXXXX.com"
  ],
  "postLogoutRedirectUri": []
}
```

and in Swagger

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            var oauthSecuritySchema = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
                {
                    AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                    {
                        AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(configuration["Idp:AuthorizationUrl"]),
                        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                        {
                            // {"Idp.UserManagement","Identity"},
                            {"openid","openid"},
                            {"profile","profile"},
                            {"email","email"}
                        },
                        TokenUrl = new Uri(configuration["Idp:TokenUrl"]),
                    }
                },
                Name = configuration["Swagger:Name"],
            };
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "Protected API", Version = "v1"});
            options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", oauthSecuritySchema);
            options.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();
            options.EnableAnnotations();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in, the Idp saves the code in the PersistedGrants table with the key formed by `(code + ":" + "authorization_code").Sha256()`. For your code `E3661868CE07773D4612B6A32A5D10B9B0A48D00E616718C795D9ED5F6827348` the key is `tJc155MKnmvPDXowrLH4laE8GBDyxFtEveiaB/ONE4w=`. That is correct according to the logs. Then, the Idp returns this code to the caller.

Then, the client can change this code for the tokens in the token endpoint. The Idp try to recover this record by forming the key again, retrieving it from the database and checking if the passed code match with the stored previously.

It seems the persistence in the operational store is not working properly. Either this record is not saved in the first part, or the query to get it in the second part is not working. Whatever the reason the service returns a generic `invalid_grant` error message.

Check if the record is saved in the PersistedGrants table. You can use my [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/REQW03) to form the key and test with other codes.

Check the previous logs if you have any EF exception when SaveAsync is called.